# Python's eval() and globals()

Tags: python, eval

I'm trying to execute a number of functions using eval(), and I need to create some kind of environment for them to run. It is said in documentation that you can pass globals as a second parameter to eval().

But it seems to not work in my case. Here's the simpified example (I tried two approaches, declaring variable global and using globals(), and both do not work):

#### File *script.py*:

```
import test

global test_variable
test_variable = 'test_value'
g = globals()
g['test_variable'] = 'test_value'
eval('test.my_func()', g)
```

#### File *test.py*:

```
def my_func():
    global test_variable
    print repr(test_variable)
```

And I'm getting:

> NameError: global name 'test_variable' is not defined.

What should I do to pass that `test_variable` into `my_func()`? Assuming I can't pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*test_variable* should be global in test.py.  You're getting a name error because you're trying to declare a variable global that doesn't yet exist.

So your my_test.py file should be like this:

```
test_variable = None

def my_func():
    print test_variable
```

And running this from the command prompt:

```
>>> import my_test
>>> eval('my_test.my_func()')
None
>>> my_test.test_variable = 'hello'
>>> my_test.test_variable
'hello'
>>> eval('my_test.my_func()')
hello
```

Generally it's bad form to use eval() and globals, so make sure you know what your doing.

Comment: Sorry, but the last sentence is "Assuming I can't pass it as a parameter."

Comment: `global test_variable` in test.py doesn't work either, I guess it's because it's in another module, and you are running that code in the interpreter.

Comment: sorry bad skimming habits, try this

Answer (score 4):

*Please correct me Python experts if I am wrong. I am also learning Python. The following is my current understanding of why the `NameError` exception was thrown.*

In Python, you cannot create a variable that can be access across modules without specifying the module name (i.e. to access the global variable `test` in module `mod1` you need to use `mod1.test` when you in module `mod2`). The scope of the global variable is pretty much limited to the module itself.

Thus when you have following in `test.py`:

```
def my_func():
    global test_variable
    print repr(test_variable)
```

The `test_variable` here refers to `test.test_variable` (i.e. `test_variable` in the `test` module namespace).

So setting `test_variable` in `script.py` will put the variable in the `__main__` namespace (`__main__` because this is the top-level module/script you provided to the Python interpreter to execute). Thus, this `test_variable` will be in a different namespace and not in the `test` module namespace where it is required to be. Hence, Python generates a `NameError` because it cannot find the variable after searching the `test` module global namespace and built-in namespace (local function namespace is skipped because of the `global` statement).

Therefore, for `eval` to work, you need to set `test_variable` in the `test` module namespace in `script.py`:

```
import test
test.test_variable = 'test_value'
eval('test.my_func()')
```

For more details about Python’s scope and namespaces see: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-name-spaces