# Turn string into operator

Tags: python, evaluation

How can I turn a string such as `"+"` into the operator plus?

Comment: instead you can convert other things to string and evaluate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729248/python-eval-and-globals

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use a lookup table:

```
import operator
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub } # etc.

print(ops["+"](1,1)) # prints 2
```

Answer (score 46):

```
import operator

ops = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.truediv,  # use operator.div for Python 2
    '%' : operator.mod,
    '^' : operator.xor,
}

def eval_binary_expr(op1, oper, op2):
    op1, op2 = int(op1), int(op2)
    return ops[oper](op1, op2)

print(eval_binary_expr(*("1 + 3".split())))
print(eval_binary_expr(*("1 * 3".split())))
print(eval_binary_expr(*("1 % 3".split())))
print(eval_binary_expr(*("1 ^ 3".split())))
```

Comment: In python3, this gives:
'+' : operator.add,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: The problem is that the poorly-named `operator` parameter clashes with the imported operator module. I'm guessing you inlined `get_operator_fn` with `eval_binary_expr`. Change the `operator` parameter to something else, like `oper`, and all references to it.  See my edit.

Comment: For Python3, you'll also have to change `operator.div` to `operator.truediv`, and fix all the print statements.

Comment: Note: This rebuilds the lookup `dict` from scratch on every call, removing the `O(1)` lookup benefit. Define the `dict` outside the function so it's only built once.

Comment: More thoroughly, @PaulMcG, Python3 drops operator.div for operator.truediv (returning a float) and operator.floordiv (Python2 style integer division)

Comment: For a full manual, visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: for exponent you want '**' : operator.pow

Answer (score 20):

How about using a lookup dict, but with lambdas instead of operator library.

```
op = {'+': lambda x, y: x + y,
      '-': lambda x, y: x - y}
```

Then you can do:

```
print(op['+'](1,2))
```

And it will output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try using eval(), but it's dangerous if the strings are not coming from you.
Else you might consider creating a dictionary:

```
ops = {"+": (lambda x,y: x+y), "-": (lambda x,y: x-y)}
```

etc... and then calling

```
ops['+'] (1,2)
```

or, for user input:

```
if ops.haskey(userop):
    val = ops[userop](userx,usery)
else:
    pass #something about wrong operator
```

Comment: **[Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer](/q/1832940). It [cannot easily be sandboxed, and proper sandboxing is harder than using a proper tool for the job.](/q/3068139)**

Answer (score 7):

There is a magic method corresponding to every operator

```
OPERATORS = {'+': 'add', '-': 'sub', '*': 'mul', '/': 'div'}

def apply_operator(a, op, b):

    method = '__%s__' % OPERATORS[op]
    return getattr(b, method)(a)

apply_operator(1, '+', 2)
```

Comment: this works well, thanks for sharing. for validation we can extend apply_operator. 
if op == '/' and b == 0:
 return np.inf
if op == '/' and a == 0:
 return 0

Comment: This doesn't let [NotImplemented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `eval()` if it is safe (not on servers, etc):

```
num_1 = 5

num_2 = 10

op = ['+', '-', '*']

result = eval(f'{num_1} {op[0]} {num_2}')

print(result)
```

Output :
15

Comment: Use of `eval` is discouraged for security risks.

Comment: **[Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer](/q/1832940). It [cannot easily be sandboxed, and proper sandboxing is harder than using a proper tool for the job.](/q/3068139)**

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to do something like:
5"+"7 
where all 3 things would be passed by variables,
so
example:

```
import operator

#define operators you wanna use
allowed_operators={
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv}

#sample variables
a=5
b=7
string_operator="+"

#sample calculation => a+b
result=allowed_operators[string_operator](a,b)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I was bugged with the same problem, using Jupyter Notebook, I was unable to import the operator module. So the above code helped give me insight but was unable to run on the platform. I figured out a somehwhat primitive way to do so with all the basic funcs and here it is: (This could be heavily refined but it’s a start…)

```
# Define Calculator and fill with input variables
# This example "will not" run if aplha character is use for num1/num2 
def calculate_me():
    num1 = input("1st number: ")
    oper = input("* OR / OR + OR - : ")
    num2 = input("2nd number: ")

    add2 = int(num1) + int(num2)
    mult2 = int(num1) * int(num2)
    divd2 = int(num1) / int(num2)
    sub2 = int(num1) - int(num2)

# Comparare operator strings 
# If input is correct, evaluate operand variables based on operator
    if num1.isdigit() and num2.isdigit():
        if oper is not "*" or "/" or "+" or "-":
            print("No strings or ints for the operator")
        else:
            pass
        if oper is "*":
            print(mult2)
        elif oper is "/":
            print(divd2)
        elif oper is "+":
            print(add2)
        elif oper is "-":
            print(sub2)
        else:
            return print("Try again")

# Call the function
calculate_me()
print()
calculate_me()
print()
```