# is it possible for me to use variable to represent '+-*/' in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to achieve function without using:

```
if op == '+':

    return a+b

if op == '-':

    return a+b

if op == '*':

    return a+b

if op == '/':

    return a+b
```

```
def calculator():
    """op will be a sign that used between a and b, a op b ==?"""

    a = int(input('a: '))
    b = int(input('b: '))
    op = (input('op: '))
    basic = ['+','-','*','/']
    if op not in basic:
        return 'this is a base calculator, use + - * / only'
    else:
        return a op b
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn string into operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `eval(f"{a}{op}{b}")`, but it's a security risk.

A better approach might be use [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), which are function wrappers on the primitive operations (but we still need a dict to convert the symbol to a name):

```
import operator

ops = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv,
}
a = 7
b = 6
op = "*"
print(ops[op](a, b)) # => 42
```

You could wrap this in a `try`/`except` block to catch unsupported operations (and division by zero):

```
import operator

def calculate(op, a, b):
    try:
        return {
            "+": operator.add,
            "-": operator.sub,
            "*": operator.mul,
            "/": operator.truediv,
        }[op](a, b) 
    except KeyError: pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = int(input('a: '))
    b = int(input('b: '))
    op = input('op: ')
    result = calculate(op, a, b)

    if result is None:
        print('this is a base calculator, use + - * / only')
    else:
        print(result)
```

It's a good idea to move user interaction outside of the function to enforce [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Todo: improve error handling if user fails to enter an `int` and add a loop for multiple prompts.

Comment: Thanks, much more elegant now !

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem. Thanks.