# converting between operator and its textual representation

Tags: python

Is there a way that I can "unparse" one of the operators back into its textual form? For instance converting `operator.__le__` to `<=`. I know I can do that using if-then-else but I thought maybe there is a simpler way to do so.

Comment: Perhaps a dict? `ops = {operator.__le__ : '<=', operator.__lt__: '<', ...}`

Comment: The closest you can do is something like `operator.add.__name__` which will give you `'add'`. For anything else you will have to create a mapping, kinda the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator)