# Python: Logical operators as functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a simple parser that should be able to read some logic and arithmetic, compile it into an AST, then evaluate it. In an effort to do so without using the evil `eval`, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740761/2328163).

Then I realized, the builtin `operator` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) has functions for almost everything, except the logical `and` and `or`, only the bitwise ones exist. Surprisingly, logical `not` also exists. Why is `and` and `or` missing? Why `not` but not `and` and `or`? And to follow the mentioned above answer, what function should I use for those two operators?

**PS:** I was checking for python3, but it looks like the same library in python2 has the same issue.

Comment: @hansolo But `not` is a keyword too. And yet it is an operator and has an equivalent function.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement logical equivalent of the bitwise operators by using [`operator.truth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth) to convert the object to it's `bool()` value & then applying the bitwise operator:

```
from operator import truth, and_, or_


def logical_and(a, b):
    return and_(truth(a), truth(b))

def logical_or(a, b):
    return or_(truth(a), truth(b))

print(logical_and([], ''))
print(logical_or([], 'x'))
```

Result:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Sure, it is very easy to work around the whole thing. My question is about the underlying implementation of `and` and `or`. It's my understanding that the operator functions are how the actual operators eventually execute. So if `+` calls `operator.add` what does `and` do?

Comment: Actually it's t he other way around. `operator` functions are utility functions that just use the normal `&` & `|` operators. Those operators themselves are implemented by the Runtime (in C). You can check the source code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/operator.py

Comment: By extension: `and` & `or` are also implemented in C - and (I guess) the authors decided not to include the equivalent in `operator` since the building blocks were already there & they would be easy to implement as I've done in my answer above