# How do I make this variable a string while working inside a float, in python?

Tags: python

I'm messing around trying to make a calculator and I have 2 user inputs and an operation:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
op = input("Enter an operation: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter a second number: "))
```

and I want to make a variable for the result number:

```
num3 = float(num1 + op + num2)
```

but I don't know how to separate the operation so it will still be a string

Comment: If `2` and `3` are entered `num3` should be `5`?

Comment: `op` already *is a string*. That isn't the problem. The problem is you can't use a `str` like that. Not, to solve the proximal problem, `num1` and `num2` should just be strings, but your fundamental problem is that `float("2.0 + 2.0")` is not going to work. You probably want to use `eval`, although, that is almost *never* the right approach in realistic scenarios.

Comment: You want to apply the string `op` as a real operator ?

Comment: `ast` library and `literal_eval` might be a safe approach to take.  

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: if you only have 2 numbers and 1 operator, you can try if clauses: `if op == "+": num1+num2`

Comment: According to the answer by [Amnon][1], You can use operator library in python and add all the symbols required. For your use case, you can write num3 = ops[op](num1,num2)


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740759/10451749

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the middle section I made.

Before I get num3 I have a list of if and elif statements for various operations:

`if op == "+":`
`    print(num1 + num2)`

`elif op == "-":`
`    print(num1 - num2)`

`elif op == "*":`
`    print(num1 * num2)`

`elif op == "/":`
`    print(num1 / num2)`

`elif op == "^":`
`    print(num1 ** num2)`

`else:`
`    print("Invalid")`

Comment: I want to have a result number and the way I thought to do it was to take whatever the user input was for num1 and num2 and use it with their input for the operation, then make it = num3