# Evaluating list with operators

Tags: python, evaluation

```
import operator

ops = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.truediv
}
n = input()
li = [n.split()]
li[0,2,4,6,8] = int(li[0,2,4,6,8])
li[1,3,5,7] = ops(li[1,3,5,7])
print(li)
```

I used this code above. I took help from [Turn string into operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator/1740759#1740759). So what I wanted to do was take in for example:

```
1 * 3 / 2 * 5 + 1
```

and split it into a list and then make the operators into operators and all the numbers integers. Then solve it as an equation.

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: "I used this code" and "I wanted to do X" aren't questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to evaluate an expression you can use `eval`, which takes an infix expression (in the form of a string) and evaluates it (assuming it's a valid expression)

```py
exp = input() # 4 + 3 * 2
answer = eval(exp) # 10
```