# Dataframe loc with parameter str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have an interface which gets a str with the condition to be executed.

Is it possible to directly pass this str in my pandas loc?

example:

```
df:
{'col A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
'col B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}

entry_str = "col A == 2"

df = df.loc[entry_str]
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to retrieve the lines that match the filter

Comment: One possible way to do this is to split the `entry_str` with comparison operators like `==`, `>` or `>=`. Then use answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/10315163). I think it will be more easier if you can seperate column name, comparison operators and value from `entry_str` in your interface.

Comment: If you want to turn string type operators to function, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1740726/10315163). You could visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html for more operators.

Answer (score 0):

just use `df.query('col A == 2')`