# Alternatives to solver.Add("x + y < 5") string representation of constraint formula

Tags: or-tools

I have OR-Tools running in a Python on Linux Azure Function.

I'd like to make this an API end point where I can post a JSON representation of an Integer Programming problem and receive a solution back.

```py
# Grab the POST data as an object
req_json = req.get_json()

# Create the MIP solver BOP/SAT/CBC
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('BOP')

# Create the variables
x = {}
for i in range(len(req_json['Variables'])):
    x[i] = solver.IntVar(0, req_json['Variables'][i]['UpperBound'], req_json['Variables'][i]['Name'])
print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables())

# Create the constraints
for j in range(len(req_json['Constraints'])):
    solver.Add(req_json['Constraints'][j]['Formula'])
print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())
```

However it seems like `solver.Add()` does not support a string representation of the formula, it's expecting an object like `solver.Add(x + y < 5)`, so is there another way to do this?

My variables and constraint formulas are dynamic and will be provided by another system. I've had a look at using [Arrays to define the model](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/mip_var_array) instead, but my formulas are quite complex and I'm not sure I'd be able to reduce them to an array of constraint coefficients.

Comment: A solution was answered on another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754900/convert-string-representation-of-a-comparison-formula-back-to-formula/65768409#65768409) specifically for Python.

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse the constraint yourself, a dirty way would be something like:

```py
formula = "x + y + z == 0"
formula = re.sub(
    r"[^\s]+",
    lambda m: f'x["{m.group(0)}"]' if m.group(0).isalpha() else m.group(0),
    formula,
)
solver.Add(eval(formula))
```

But `eval` isn't recommended.

Look up each term in the variables dict and do the same for the operators ([Turn string into operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator)) or maybe try something like `LoadModelFromProto`+`ExportModelToProto` or `ExportModelAsMpsFormat`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at `eval()` but that actually tries to execute/calculate the formula. `solver.Add()` is expecting a formula object. I'll edit the question to include an accurate example.

Comment: I'll have a look at the Export/Import options though thanks.

Comment: This was the right track. I just wasn't familiar enough with Python to execute.