# Using a symbol form a string in python calculation

Tags: python

I have a string of calculations which I parsed to get first operand, second operand and symbol used in calculation.

```
op01, sym0, op02 = "1", "+", "5"
```

Now I want to perform calculation on it but could not figure out how?
I want

```
op01 sym0 op02
```

which should become:

```
1 + 5
```

and give the result:

```
6
```

Comment: Hello. You seem to have tagged your question with the Python tag. Would you mind sharing some python code you've written so far?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Isn't there any simple way other than learning Py.parsing. Like its just this line and I can complete my program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn string into operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1740726/6045800)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I would love to but the code is of a program and I would really really not want to disclose it. Pls. understand : )

Comment: There's multiple answers in the marked duplicate. Not all of them use pyparsing

Comment: You don't need to post the exact code you're working on. That's why we ask you create a [mcve]

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thx it's simple and easy. And

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry for code and the link with which my questions was merge, none of solution is as simple and valid as the one below. Therefore I think it deserveD to be a standalone question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer   Sorry, I was rude to you.

Comment: Why it *"deserve[s] to be a standalone question"*? The answer below is exactly as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740759/6045800). @OneCricketeer Can you please replace the dupe target?

Comment: It's fine. IMO, the solutions there aren't "simple" because they are made to handle all possible operators, and most math expressions, not just simple addition

Comment: Sorry I am a noob.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator` module provides functions that correspond to each of the operators, but there is no predefined mapping of the symbols to their intended implementation. You'll have to define that yourself.

```
import operator

ops = {"+": operator.add}

op01, sym0, op02 = "1", "+", "5"

print(ops[sym0](int(op01), int(op02)))  # Outputs 6
```

Comment: This code outputs 15! Help

Comment: Overlooked the conversion, sorry.