# dynamic numpy conditions based on values from array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find out how I can use `np.where` in a dynamic way, where I select some predefined values, pass them to a function and let them create the condition.
Ideally I want to create long conditions with several logical
operators.

In the code below I am stupidly trying to use a string:

`cond_arr[1]['cond']` as a logical operator, to illustrate what I want, because I can't find out how to proceed with this?

Is there an elegant(or just working) way to create these dynamic conditions?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    'open': [random.uniform(50, 100) for _ in range(30)],
    'high': [random.uniform(100, 150) for _ in range(30)],
    'low': [random.uniform(25, 50) for _ in range(30)],
    'close': [random.uniform(50, 100) for _ in range(30)],
    'volume': [random.randint(1000, 10000) for _ in range(30)],
    'datetime': [datetime(2023, 10, 1, 0, 0) + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(30)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# The meat and potatoes

indicators = [{"ind": "open"},{"ind": "rsi"}, {"ind": "macd"}]
conds = [{"cond": "<"}, {"cond": ">"}, {"cond": "=="}, {"cond": "and"}, {"cond": "or"}]
values = [{"val": 10}, {"val": 100}, {"val": 15}, {"val": 17}, {"val": 18}, {"val": 7}]


def create_condition(cond_array):
    print(f'{cond_array[0]["ind"]}')  # Use double curly braces to escape
    
    #df["signal"] = np.where(df["open"] > 10, 1, -1) <-- what i want to do below
    df["signal"] = np.where(df[f'{cond_array[0]["ind"]}'] cond_arr[1]['cond']  df[f'{cond_array[2 ["val"]}'], 1, -1)


selected_conds = [indicators[0],conds[0],values[0]]

create_condition(selected_conds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) to evaluate a dynamic expression:

```
def make_clause(df, col_d, cond_d, val_d):
    col, cond, val = col_d['ind'], cond_d['cond'], val_d['val']
    df["signal"] = np.where(pd.eval(f'df.{col} {cond} {val}',
                                    target=df), 1, -1)


selected_conds = [indicators[0], conds[0], values[0]]
make_clause(df, *selected_conds)
```

---

In case if a target column name contains spaces, use `f'df["{col}"] {cond} {val}'` as an expression.

Comment: Thank you What a beautifull function, makes me love python!

Answer (score 2):

Use [**operators**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator), for easy mapping is created dictionary `d` by flatten list of dictionaries:

```
from collections import ChainMap

selected_conds = [indicators[0],conds[0],values[0]]
d = dict(ChainMap(*selected_conds))
print (d)
{'val': 10, 'cond': '<', 'ind': 'open'}
   

import operator

ops = {'>': operator.gt,
        '<': operator.lt,
       '>=': operator.ge,
       '<=': operator.le,
       '==': operator.eq,
        '!=': operator.ne,
        'and': operator.and_,
        'or': operator.or_}

#df["signal"] = np.where(df["open"] < 10, 1, -1)
df["signal"] = np.where(ops[d['cond']](df[d['ind']], d['val']), 1, -1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! learned both about chainmap and import operator