# How to replace the if statements with functions and call them

Tags: python, function, calculator

This is a Python code that works as a simple calculator!
There are multiple if statements to continue the main loop.
I wrote it so that when the input end with '$' the program restarts.
But as a good coding practise you shouldn't repeat the same code right?
So I want to replace those multiple if statements with a function so that I can call the function when needed to continue the loop. If you have a better idea that would also suffice!

```
def get_user_input(prompt):
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        print(user_input)

        if user_input.endswith('$'):
            return '$'
        elif user_input.endswith('#'):
            exit()
        else:
            return user_input


while True:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add      : + ")
    print("2.Subtract : - ")
    print("3.Multiply : * ")
    print("4.Divide   : / ")
    print("5.Power    : ^ ")
    print("6.Remainder: % ")
    print("7.Terminate: # ")
    print("8.Reset    : $ ")


    restart = False

    while True:
        choice = get_user_input("Enter choice (+, -, *, /, ^, %, #, $): ")
        if choice == '$':
            restart = True
            break
        if choice not in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%", '$'):
            print('Unrecognised operation')
            continue

        elif choice in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%", '$'):
            break

    if restart is True:
        continue


    while True:
        first_number = get_user_input('First number: ')
        if first_number == '$':
            restart =  True
            break
        try:
            first_operand = float(first_number)
            break

        except :
            print('unidentified operand')
            continue

    if restart is True:
        continue

    while True:
        second_number = get_user_input('Second number: ')
        if second_number == '$':
            restart = True
            break
        try:
            second_operand = float(second_number)
            break

        except:
            print('unidentified operand')
            continue
    if restart is True:
        continue

    if choice == '+':
        result = first_operand + second_operand
        print(result)

    elif choice == '-':
        result = first_operand - second_operand
        print(result)

    elif choice == '*':
        result = first_operand * second_operand
        print(result)

    elif choice == '/':
        try:
            result = first_operand/second_operand
            print(result)
        except:
            print("Can't divide by zero")

    elif choice == '^':
        result = first_operand ** second_operand
        print(result)

    elif choice == '%':
        result = first_operand % second_operand
        print(result)

    while True:
        proceed = input('Want to perform another calculation(Y/N)').upper()

        if proceed == 'Y':
            break
        elif proceed == 'N':
            exit()
        elif proceed.endswith('$'):
            boool = True
            break
        else:
            print('Unrecognised answer')
            continue
    if proceed == 'Y' or boool is True :
        continue
```

Comment: how many while loops do you have in your program?

Comment: You can use operator library. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could add more parameters to your `get_user_input` function. For instance, a *function* that will be called to validate the input, and a *message* when that validation returns a rejection:

```
def get_user_input(prompt, validator, error_msg):
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        print(user_input)

        if user_input.endswith('$'):
            return "$"
        if user_input.endswith('#'):
            exit()
        # If the validator function returns False or raises an error
        #    ... it means the input does not pass validation
        try:
            if validator(user_input) is not False:
                return user_input
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print(error_msg)
```

Now you can pass these as arguments. For instance, the first input could happen as follows:

```
    choice = get_user_input("Enter choice (+, -, *, /, ^, %, #, $): ",
                            lambda x: x in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%"),
                            "Unrecognised operation")
    if choice == '$':
        continue
```

The `lambda` part is the function that will be called by `get_user_input`.

For the second and third input you could consider that they are very similar, and so you could use a loop that makes two iterations: one for each input number. The validator function to pass to `get_user_input` is quite simple here; it can be just the function `float`:

```
    operands = []
    for prompt in ("First number: ", "Second number: "):
        number = get_user_input(prompt, float, "unidentified operand")
        if number == '$':
            break
        operands.append(float(number))
```

Now you will have two numbers in `operands`. We can use the `else` clause of the `for` statement to know whether no break was executed.

For performing the different arithmetic operations, you could create a dictionary with the arithmetic operators as keys, and with functions as corresponding values. You might even rely on the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) to already have these functions made for you. Here I will just define them with `lambda`:

```
funcs = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
    '^': lambda a, b: a ** b,
    '%': lambda a, b: a % b,
}
```

Now you can call the intended function by unpacking the operands as arguments (`*`):

```
result = funcs[choice](*operands)
```

Finally, the last `input` you make for the yes/no answer, could also benefit from the `get_user_input` function.

Here is everything put together:

```
def get_user_input(prompt, validator, error_msg):
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        print(user_input)

        if user_input.endswith('$'):
            return "$"
        if user_input.endswith('#'):
            exit()
        try:
            if validator(user_input) is not False:
                return user_input
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print(error_msg)

funcs = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
    '^': lambda a, b: a ** b,
    '%': lambda a, b: a % b,
}

while True:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add      : + ")
    print("2.Subtract : - ")
    print("3.Multiply : * ")
    print("4.Divide   : / ")
    print("5.Power    : ^ ")
    print("6.Remainder: % ")
    print("7.Terminate: # ")
    print("8.Reset    : $ ")

    choice = get_user_input("Enter choice (+, -, *, /, ^, %, #, $): ",
                            lambda x: x in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%"),
                            "Unrecognised operation")
    if choice == '$':
        continue

    operands = []
    for prompt in ("First number: ", "Second number: "):
        number = get_user_input(prompt, float, "unidentified operand")
        if number == '$':
            break
        operands.append(float(number))
    else:
        try:
            result = funcs[choice](*operands)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            result = "Can't divide by zero"
        print(result)
    
        if get_user_input("Want to perform another calculation (Y/N) ",
                          lambda x: x.upper() in ("Y", "N"),
                          "Unrecognised answer").upper() == 'N':
            break
```

Comment: Surely we don’t want `except:`, right?

Comment: I suppose you mean that exception types should be added. I updated the answer with `ValueError` for the validator, and `ZeroDivisionError` for the arithmetic operation.